# mysql RAND() LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a query like this:

```
    SELECT otel_id 
        FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
        WHERE YAZILIM_menu_icerik.menu_id = 39 
        AND otel_id IN (
                        SELECT otel_id 
                        FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
                        WHERE menu_id =$id 
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        ) 
        LIMIT 0,20
```

It should display randomly 20 hotels each time it works but instead , i'm ending up getting the same 20 hotel each time. Long story short `RAND()` doesn't seem to work and I can't seem to find any logical error.

EDIT: Problem solved. Mysql doesn't see inner RAND() so here's the correct way to do it:

```
SELECT otel_id 
    FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
    WHERE YAZILIM_menu_icerik.menu_id = 39 
    AND otel_id IN (
                    SELECT otel_id 
                    FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
                    WHERE menu_id =$id 
                   )
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is terribly inefficient - you should probably try and find another solution. Regardless, if you move the `ORDER BY RAND()` to outside the `)`, does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses should be together:

```
SELECT otel_id 
FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
WHERE YAZILIM_menu_icerik.menu_id = 39
AND otel_id IN 
(
    SELECT otel_id 
    FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik 
    WHERE menu_id = $id 
)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

It makes no sense to have a bare `ORDER BY` in a subquery with no `LIMIT` clause because the ordering is not necessarily preserved in the results of the outer query.

Comment: Problem solved

SELECT otel_id FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik WHERE YAZILIM_menu_icerik.menu_id = 39 AND otel_id IN
(SELECT otel_id FROM YAZILIM_menu_icerik WHERE menu_id =$id ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20";

Answer (score 4):

ORDER BY RAND() is bad solution. Your indexes are ignored. Particularly difficult situation with large amounts of data.

Alternative if you have primary key on id :

```
    SELECT b1.* FROM Bugs AS b1 JOIN 
(SELECT CEIL( RAND()* (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Bugs)) AS id) AS b2 
 WHERE b1.id >= b2.id ORDER BY b1.id LIMIT 1
```