# Show unique random records within LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

NOTE: The possible duplicate [mysql RAND() LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797553/mysql-rand-limit) did not address the answer because in my sql my ORDER BY and LIMIT already are together.

I'd like to show unique random records but within a range, but when I use RAND() in my sql it pulls random records from beyond my limit range:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cases.caseid, cases.img, casetypes.casetypeid, cases.cost
FROM cases, casetypes
WHERE cases.caseid =  casetypes.caseid AND casetypes.mastercaseid = $mastercaseid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $lastrow, $perPage
```

EDIT: This worked for me based on answer below:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT cases.caseid, cases.img, casetypes.casetypeid, cases.cost
FROM cases, casetypes
 WHERE cases.caseid =  casetypes.caseid AND casetypes.mastercaseid = $mastercaseid
 LIMIT $lastrow, $perPage
 ) x
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Why not just add another condition to the `WHERE` clause to restrict to a certain range?  The `LIMIT` clause should still return the number of records you want, assuming there are that many available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql RAND() LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797553/mysql-rand-limit)

Comment: @CoderofCode I saw that post, but my ORDER BY and LIMIT already are together.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I implement my LIMIT OFFSET in the WHERE clause?

Comment: sample data. Sample output.

Comment: don't edit your question to add the right answer to it. Accept and/or upvote the answers instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, one option is to do a subselect so that you can do the limit before your do the order by:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT cases.caseid, cases.img, casetypes.casetypeid, cases.cost
FROM cases, casetypes
WHERE cases.caseid =  casetypes.caseid AND casetypes.mastercaseid = $mastercaseid
LIMIT $lastrow, $perPage
) x

ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: hmm, I don't really understand this. Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Can you integrate your example with my specific SQL? I don't see how I can do this but also keep my columns accessible.

Comment: I did this but it doesn't work for me. I get this error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @obreezy you can add any name/letter after the derived table. Try it again, please.

Comment: Oh ok, so by adding the random x, the way you had it prior worked: placing the ORDER BY RAND() outside the subselect and the LIMIT inside! You can change that and I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @obreezy oh I see what you're after. I made that modification.