# unable to generate multiple random words at a time using order by rand using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

Hi friends am trying to produce random words using order by rand but unable to produce.Here is my code

```
for($i=0;$i< 10;$i++) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    if (!$result) {
        /*die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());*/
        die("Query failed".mysqli_error());
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $meta_descriptions = '{'  $row['fact'] . '&nbsp;' . '|' $row['fact'] . '|' . $row['fact']}';
        echo $meta_descriptions;               
    }  
}
```

My questions table has one column that is column fact. i t has three values like

```
    apple
    ball
    cat
```

Am getting output as

```
   ball |ball| ball only
```

I want it to be random like

```
     ball|cat|apple
```

How can I generate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797553/mysql-rand-limit) SO question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this statement inside your `while()` loop,

```
$meta_descriptions = '{'  $row['fact'] . '&nbsp;' . $row['fact'] . '}';
```

You're using same column value **two times** in each iteration of `while()` loop. Simply change your `while()` code section in the following way,

```
$meta_descriptions = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $meta_descriptions .= $row['fact'] . '|';               
}
$meta_descriptions = rtrim($meta_descriptions, '|');
echo $meta_descriptions;
```

#### Alternative method:

Create an empty array in the beginning. In each iteration of `while()` loop, push `$row['fact']` value to this array. And finally apply [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function on this array to get the desired result.

So your code should be like this:

```
$meta_descriptions = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $meta_descriptions[] = $row['fact'];               
}
$meta_descriptions = implode('|', $meta_descriptions);
echo $meta_descriptions;
```

Comment: Sorry I want '|' symbols three of the words  updated question

Comment: @shansetivikas I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

change inside your while loop.

```
$meta_descriptions = '{';
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $descriptions[] = $row['fact'];               
 }
 $meta_descriptions .= implode(" | ",descriptions);
 $meta_descriptions .= '}';
 echo $meta_descriptions;
```

Comment: Sorry I want '|' symbols three of the words  updated question

Comment: OMG you can easily do it yourself. BTW have updated.